# How to Introduce jQuery auto complete for drupal5

Tags: jquery, drupal

Hey I am new to Drupal. Can someone help me to introduce jQuery auto complete into a drupal text field.  I prefer basic coding standards.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at the Drupal Form API for [textfields](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/5#textfield). One of the attributes you can set is [#autocomplete_path](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/5#autocomplete_path). Here you can set the path that the autocomplete widget should use.

Then all that is left, return some JSON data to your ajax call. You can do this yourself with by implementing [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_menu/5). The code for the form and the menu callback should be located in a module that you create.